# VS Code disable Find in section by default

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I'm having some trouble with my VS Code Find behavior. Whenever I hit CTRL + F it gives me the Find window, but the Find in section is active (attached screenshot) as a default, which in NOT what I want. It's really annoying to click there to disable this. [image: Active Find in section]

Thank you.

Comment: Are you highlighting text when you hit CTRL+F? It might be that it defaults to this if some block of text is highlighted first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press `CTRL+<` to open the settings editor, then look for `autoFindInSelection`. Likely, it is set to `always` so change it to `never`.

Comment: Dear @Shafiq Jetha, THANK YOU, that was it! It was driving me nuts! Have a good one.